# How to see encoding progress in Compressor 4.1.3

Tags: encoding, final-cut-pro-x, x264

Is there really no way to see progress of an encoding job in Apple Compressor 4.1.3?

I started a batch (single job, one file) and this is all I see:

[image]

My fan is blowing at full speed so I guess something's happening. Or maybe it's just crashed and will never complete...

Thanks Apple

Comment: well... the job completed fine so I guess it is just a case of crap UX